# How to read Characteristic Descriptor

Tags: bluetooth, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am in the process of interfacing with a BLE server and the first attempt is to view the response from Service 0x1818 - Characterstic 0x2A65 and to find out what Cycling Power Features are supported as per this link

https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.cycling_power_feature.xml

What I get is this

```
[134,3,1,0]
```

I have read the documentation about 30 times and still cant figure out how to translate that into something useful.

**How do I parse that response and map it to features to determine what is support by the BLE service/server?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link you've sent says that the field 'Cycling Power Feature' is 32-bit, and is given LSB-first. So, your 4-bytes should be converted to binary like this (starting with MSB first):

- 'd0   → 'b0000_0000
- 'd1   → 'b0000_0001
- 'd3   → 'b0000_0011
- 'd134 → 'b1000_0110

Together you get (bits 31..0): 'b00000000_00000001_00000011_10000110

In the link, go over the meaning of each bit field, and see if it is True or False. For example:

- bit 0, value: 0 → "Pedal Power Balance Supported" is False
- bit 1, value: 1 → "Accumulated Torque Supported" is True

and so on.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to answer. I understand what you are saying but I'm not sure how I match up to the only 22 value that are available.

Comment: The field is 32 bits. Only the least 22 are meaningful. This is why all 10 msbits are 0.